# phandle kernel not looking on right address

Tags: linux-kernel, device-tree

I'm facing an issue with the kernel at boot time for one driver especially.
The phandle where he's looking for finding the node is not the one that I see on the dts file decompiled.

Here is the boot logs :

```
[   28.110920] From list_name:avdd-supply
[   28.110953] /soc/i2c@75b5000/pcm1864@4b: could not find phandle addr:0x3eb
[   28.116603] 7-004b supply avdd not found, using dummy regulator
[   28.124287] From list_name:dvdd-supply
[   28.129168] /soc/i2c@75b5000/pcm1864@4b: could not find phandle addr:0x3ec
[   28.135623] 7-004b supply dvdd not found, using dummy regulator
[   28.143282] From list_name:iovdd-supply
[   28.148178] /soc/i2c@75b5000/pcm1864@4b: could not find phandle addr:0x3ed
[   28.154621] 7-004b supply iovdd not found, using dummy regulator
```

The fullpath is correct for example `/soc/i2c@75b5000/pcm1864@4b`. He's looking for phandle of property : `avdd-supply` at the first line and he's looking at `0x3eb` physical address I guess.

When I decompile the DTBO file I see an other phandle value, let me fully print it here:

```
    pcm1864@4b {
        compatible = "ti,pcm1864";
        reg = <0x4b>;
        avdd-supply = <0x22>;
        dvdd-supply = <0x23>;
        iovdd-supply = <0x24>;
        phandle = <0x1e>;
    };
```

As you can see the phandle is `0x22` for the first one for example

So why Kernel is looking for node at `0x3eb` instead of `0x22` ?

Thanks for help

Comment: `0x22` is **value**. On opposite **phandle** is a kinda pointer in device tree which should look like `foo-bar = <&other_node_reference ...arguments...>`. Okay, according to https://elinux.org/Device_Tree_Mysteries#Phandle the value means the absolute ID of device node in the tree. *But you are not likely to find a modern device tree source file that explicitly defines a phandle or specifies a u32 value when referencing a phandle.*

Comment: Do you mean a DTBO (Device Tree Blob for Overlay) file or a DTB (Device Tree Blob) file? The phandles in overlay blobs are relative and get fixed up to absolute phandles when the overlay is loaded into the live device tree.

Comment: @0andriy yes of course, the 0x22 0x23 0x24 are pointers to other nodes. But kernel is not looking for them correcly.

Comment: @IanAbbott This is a full DTBO (yes overlay) part, bootloader should fix correctly with 0x22, 0x23, 0x24 values. I think... You are saying that the phandles I see in the DTBO file are not finals ? When bootloader will fix it won't take those values ?

Comment: The bootloader will need to add an offset to all the phandles in the overlay when it merges it into the base tree. The offset is based on the current maximum phandle value in the base tree so that all the phandles in the merged tree will be unique. It also needs to add the offset to any local phandle reference values in the overlay (such as your `avdd-supply` property value), and resolve any external phandle references from the overlay to the base tree. There are special nodes `__local_fixups__` and `__fixups__` in the overlay and `__symbols__` in the base tree to resolve the cross references.